# From client connect with server with the same network

Tags: python, python-3.x, server

I have this code to connect with server like this:

This is file server.py

```
host = "192.168.0.91"
port = 5004

s = socket.socket()
s.bind((host,port))

s.listen(5)

print("Server Started.")
```

But when I run it, it showed me an error

```
File "D:/odoo11new/server.py", line 61, in Main
s.bind((host,port))
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

How can i fix that problem :( any suggest for me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You tried to bind the host which wasn't set up on your server. 
Check host via [ipconfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ipconfig) 
Or bind any host like this:

```
host = "0.0.0.0"
```